# Manga where the main character is transported to another world with his home, which turns into a woman

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for a manga where the main character (MC) is transported to another world with his home, which turns into a woman. The MC becomes super powerful in magic and grows apple trees.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Is there anything else you can remember about the story that might help us narrow it down? When and where did you read this, for example? What other story details can you remember?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: @Krish: Since you've asked another question, don't forget you can accept this one.

Answer (score 7):

Pretty sure this is ***[My House is a Magic Power Spot - Just by Living there I Become the Strongest in the World](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/sx7q5r8/ore-no-ie-ga-maryoku-spot-datta-ken-sundeiru-dake-de-sekai-saikyou)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Living carefree at home is the greatest shortcut...my house is the world's greatest Magic Power Spot. That being the case, both my house and I were summoned to another world by some guys who were aiming for it. However, I've been living in this place for many years and my body is, apparently, abnormally overflowing with magic. Due to some unforeseen circumstances by those guys who summoned me, they quickly ran away. Be that as it may, there are still some ill-mannered people who covet the magic leaking out of my house. I won't give up my house to those people! I'm going to wield my power as I please!

The protagonist wakes up to discover that he and his house have been transported to the middle of a forest in another world. It turns out that his house is now sitting in a 'magic power spot,' which makes him incredibly powerful within that vicinity. In that world, the house also manifests a spirit that looks like a young woman, and they grow apples trees around the house, using magic.

[image]

[image]